# how to select a range of html table cell value in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Please help!
I have a html table and for example I want to select the first 4 cell value of the table but I don't know how.
I tried:
var table = document.getElementById("td")
selectedCell = table.cells[0:4]

javascript does not understand this way.

Comment: what does "selecting cells" mean exactly? Like you would drag and highlight with a mouse? Or do you want to read the contents of those cells into an array? Or something else?

Comment: This is not a spreadsheet, what made you think it will work?

Comment: @AlonEitan Office 365 / google sheets begs to differ :D

Comment: Wait, but can you really select a range, like the answer below suggests?

Comment: @AlonEitan no. You cant. Hence why its now edited

Comment: I need to take those values and add them into an array. For example I have a html table from 1 to 10, I need to take 1 to 4 from the table into an array in js. can I select those values like answer below then add them into my array by a for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access a cell by its row index and cell index like this:

```js
var table = document.getElementById('table1')

for(let rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < 2; rowIndex++){
  for(let cellIndex = 0; cellIndex < 2; cellIndex++){
     console.log(table.rows[rowIndex].cells[cellIndex]);
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="table1" style="width:100%">
  <caption>Monthly savings</caption>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$50</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>March</td>
    <td>$70</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>April</td>
    <td>$160</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

if you give some sample data and an expected output I can use it to help you to make adjustment to this.

Comment: For example: I have this table

1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25
with 5 columns and 5 rows
How can I take like 6 number from this table and add them into an array. Like when I input 6, the script can take the first 6 values from the table then add them into a array.